# VS-Code: marked code gets deleted instead of wrapped when making backticks

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, quotes, backticks

when I mark some code in VS-Code, and do some quotes, VS-Code would set a quote to the beginning, and one to the end of the marked code - when doing backticks on the other hand, VS-Code would remove the marked code, and replace it by a single backtick - is there a setting where I can tell vs code to handle backticks the same way as it does quotes or single quotes, and wrap the marked content instead of replace it??

I searched the settings but could not find any entry related to backticks and everything I've found did not look related to me.

Comment: I assume you have `Editor: Auto Surround` set to `languageDefined` or `quotes`.  It works for me with backticks in a javascript file.  You don't say what language you are using?  The surround is defined in each language's configuration, so if it isn't working for you in some other language,  it might not be defined as such.

Comment: Thanks! : )

Indeed I have set Editor: Auto Surround to languageDefined - in Windows this would work (in my current case with JavaScript & TypeScript), on Mac OS on the other hand this would lead to VS Code deletening the marked content - however, when hitting CMD+Z right after the text would be wrapped as it should be - so I guess there must be happening something additionally, right after setting the backtick? : S

...seems strange to me anways. : /